# lifecycle rule from s3 invokes lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a case where I have an s3 bucket with a lifecycle rule to delete some of the objects in it.

What I need is to trigger a lambda when the rule has finished the action of deleting the objects.

Is there a way I can attach invocation of lambdas from 3s lifecycles rules? What do I need to use?

I have seen a [tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/tutorial-lifecycle-hook-lambda.html#lambda-add-lifecycle-hook) that allows you to do it with EC2 utilizing the Amazon EventBridge rule, and as a service name, there is the option S3 On Outputs. Is there something I can do with it?

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial you linked is about EC2 Auto Scaling. This is a totally separate service, so this is not applicable to S3 lifecycle events.

What you can do, is use [an S3 event notification](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/NotificationHowTo.html) to get notified when an object is deleted. But be aware that you will get this notification for each object that gets deleted, so not only after the lifecycle rule has been executed.

Notifications for the lifecycle rule itself, do not exist as of now, but there is a feature request for this with the AWS team for some years now.